# I got a question about live method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.classname').live('click',function() { some code; });
```

Is there some problem of performance if a have about 100-200 or 300 elements with this class?

Comment: Do you have to use live? If you aren't dynamically adding these elements you can just use $('.classname').click(function() { some code; });

Comment: `live()` and `delegate()` are both now deprecated, use `on()` where possible

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on the contents of `{ some code }` Only way to tell is to set it up and test. If the performance is adequate, you have no problem. If performance is poor, then you can profile it in Firebug and/or Chrome/Safari Developer Tools, and attempt to further optimize the bound function.

Answer (score 1):

`live` and `delegate` should actually *improve* performance for large volumes of elements. That is of course in comparison to `bind`. If `live` is slow, you can practically guarantee that `bind` will be worse.

The reason for this is that a `delegate` call* stores the function on a **single** element, while a `bind` call stores a copy of the function on **every** element.

When you use a delegate, it stores the listener on a parent element that will catch the event and call the callback in the context of the child element.

Don't optimize prematurely. If you've already got issues, try separating out code into reusable chunks and see how much you can reduce. If you don't have issues, then what's the problem?

<sub>* `live` is essentially `$(document).delegate(selector,...)`</sub>